Cannot find type declaration in yarn workspace common packages
Need some help declaring global modules using yarn workspaces. Can't figure out where to put declarations so they work as expected
File structure:
root/
├── app/
├── common/
│   ├── assets/
│   │   ├── example.svg
│   ├── components/
│       ├── Icon/
│           ├── Icon.tsx
├── global.d.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json

global.d.ts
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.svg?react';
declare module '*.json';

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["./common/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/vite.config.mts", "**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "frontend-monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "types": "./global.d.ts",
  "workspaces": [
    "app",
    "common/*"
  ],
}

Importing svg for a example raises an error:
  import Example from '@common/assets/example.svg?react';

  ERROR: Cannot find module '@common/assets/example.svg?react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Note: UI works as expected. Importing other components from @common works as expected. Just issues with declarations when importing from svg, png and other extensions
EDIT:
Found the solution. For each package I created separate *.d.ts declaration file and separate tsconfig.json. Inside tsconfig added "include": ["**/*.d.ts"]
The structure would look like this, so each package needs to have it's own type declaration and tsconfig file:
root/
├── app/
├── common/
│   ├── assets/
│   │   ├── example.svg
│   │   ├── assets.d.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── Icon/
│   │   │   ├── Icon.tsx
│   │   ├── components.d.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json

